# Grant with condition in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to do the grant with the condition of a table.
the user name in the table will get the grant permisstion.

```
mysql> select * from teacher;
+------------+-----------------------+---------+----------------------------+ | 
teacher_id | teacher_name          | dept_id | subject               |

+------------+-----------------------+---------+----------------------------+ 
|          1 | Daw Khine Yin Mon     |       1 | English               | 
|          2 | Daw Ei Ei Nway        |       1 | English             | 
|          3 | Daw Thiri Kyaw        |       1 | English             | 
|          4 | U Nay Lin Soe         |       1 | English             | 
|          5 | Daw Zin Mar Thwal     |       1 | English             |
```

This is the teacher table and I do them as a user by ...

```
Create user 'Daw Khine Yin Mo' identified by 'asd';
Create user 'Daw Ei Ei Nway' identified by 'asd';
Create user 'Daw Thiri Kyaw' identified by 'asd';
Create user 'U Nay Lin Soe' identified by 'asd';
Create user 'Daw Zin Mar Thw' identified by 'asd';
```

I grant them as ...

```
Grant select(teacher_id,rate_no) on rating to 'Daw Khine Yin Mo','Daw Ei Ei Nway';
```

I want to make condition such ...

```
Grant select(teacher_id,rate_no) on rating to 'Daw Khine Yin Mo' where teacher.teacher_name ='Daw Khine Yin Mon';
```

How can i do that ?

Comment: Create a view, grant select on the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a view and then grant access to that view.

```
CREATE VIEW 
     viewName
AS
     SELECT(teacher_id,rate_no) 
     FROM RATING 
     WHERE teacher.teacher_name ='Daw Khine Yin Mon'

GRANT ALL ON viewName TO 'Daw Khine Yin Mo'
```

Comment: Thanks, that is helpful.
I created each of the teacher as user. so i should do each VIEW for each user?